# How to allow tag inheritance only for headlines that have tags themselves?

Tags: org-mode, org-tags

Consider the following headline structure with tags:

```
* Recipes :recipe:

** Pizza :unhealthy:
*** Ingredients
*** How to

** Burrito :unhealthy:
*** Ingredients
*** How to

** Salad :healthy:
*** Ingredients
*** How to
```

Let's assume I want to get all my unhealthy recipes. So I filter my agenda for the tags `:recipe:unhealthy:`. The problem is, now I get Pizza and Burrito, but also their sub headlines Ingredients and How to, which I am not really interested  in at this moment. I just want to get my unhealthy recipes, right?

**Result should be:**

```
Pizza :recipe:unhealthy:
Burrito :recipe:unhealthy:
```

Is there a way, so that tags are only inherited on the headlines that themselves also have a tag? In this case, `:recipe:` will only be inherited to Pizza, Burrito and Salad, but not to Ingredients and How to. The tag `:unhealthy:` will also not be inherited to Ingredients and How to, as they do not have any tags.

I do not really want to use tag hierarchies, because not everything that will be tagged with `:unhealthy:` is a recipe.

I am also happy with other ways of solving this problem.

Comment: Not an answer, but you can also search by level.  If all the recipe headlines you want to find are on the same level, just add `LEVEL=2` to your search.